# tensorflow-cpu - ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type int)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, cpu

I am starting to study deep running. I got a problem when I made some code.
Please, let me know to solve the problem.
I have no idea to solve it.
I installed the `tensorflow-cpu`. Is it a problem? Do I need a graphic card?

-my error-

```
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type int).
```

-code`-

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

samsung=pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\XNOTE\Desktop\Deepstudy\pred 
test\samsung.csv", index_col=0, header=0, encoding='cp949', sep=',')

for i in range(len(samsung.index)):
    for j in range(len(samsung.iloc[i])):
        samsung.iloc[i,j] = int(samsung.iloc[i,j].replace(',',''))

samsung=samsung.sort_values(['일자'], ascending=[True])

samsung=samsung.values


# code split 
def split_xy5(dataset, time_steps, y_column):
    x,y=list(), list()
    for i in range(len(dataset)):
        x_end_number=i+time_steps
        y_end_number=x_end_number + y_column

        if y_end_number > len(dataset):
            break
        tmp_x = dataset[i:x_end_number, :]
        tmp_y = dataset[x_end_number : y_end_number, 3]
        x.append(tmp_x)
        y.append(tmp_y)
    return np.array(x), np.array(y)
    
x,y = split_xy5(samsung, 5, 1)


from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, random_state=1, test_size = 0.3)

x_train = np.reshape(x_train,(x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1] * x_train.shape[2]))
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (x_test.shape[0], x_test.shape[1]*x_test.shape[2]))
print(x_train.shape)
print(x_test.shape)

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(x_train)
x_train_scaled = scaler.transform(x_train)
x_test_scaled = scaler.transform(x_test)
print(x_train_scaled[0,:])

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(64, input_shape = (25, )))
model.add(Dense(32, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(32, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(32, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(32, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mse'])

from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(patience=20)
model.fit(x_train_scaled, y_train, validation_split=0.2, 
verbose=1, batch_size=1, epochs=100, callbacks=[early_stopping])

loss, mse = model.evaluate(x_test_scaled, y_test, batch_size=1)
print('loss : ', loss)
print('mse : ', mse)

y_pred = model.predict(x_test_scaled)

for i in range(5):
    print('종가 : "', y_test[i], '/ 예측가 : ', y_pred[i])
```

> Load file and make array to use numpy.
> Make a model, but it doesn`t not work
> Blockquote

Comment: You don't need a graphic card. Graphic card gpu will accelerate the computation, otherwise both cpu and gpu are doing the same calculations. But, to reproduce the error, you need to post which part of your code fails.

Comment: As @AhmetTavli said it has nothing to do with CPU or GPU. However, you can post your code as well so it would be easier to help you with your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `x_train_scaled` is supposed to be of type int and you're getting an error at model.fit, you can try this:

`tf.cast(x_train_scaled, tf.int32)`

you can do the same for y_train and other test arrays and cast them to the desired tensorflow dtype.